# is it true that $Range(T) \subset Range(T^*)$ always?

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

is it true that $Range(T) \subset Range(T^*)$ always? or, in some special case.  How to prove ? Only a hint is enough.

Answer (score 1):

$\pmatrix{1&1\\ 0&0}$.